# MFMailComposeViewController and UITextField category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have UITextField category. WIth this category MFMailComposeViewController won't work, its crash when I present MFMailComposeViewController and have error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 24.5]'
```

---

```
@implementation UITextField (SomeCategory)

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset( bounds , 30 , 5);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset( bounds , 30 , 5);
}

@end
```

anybody know how fix this?

Comment: It is always a ***terrible*** idea to override methods in a category.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    if (CGRectIsNull(bounds) || CGRectIsInfinite(bounds)) {
        return bounds;
    }
    return CGRectInset( bounds , 30 , 5);
}
```

And the same for your second function.

You should rename the functions though, so that they don't conflict with the existing methods, or subclass instead of using a category.

Comment: its not work,if I rename a function, the custom UITextField dosn't work

Comment: Well, as I said, you should subclass then.  :-)

Comment: This should, however, fix your crash.